Find the limit of the recursive sequence using the associated function
I have to find the limit of the following recursive sequence:
$x_0=0; x_{n+1}=2x_n^3-x_n+\frac{5}{3\sqrt{6}}$
To study the monotony of the sequence I have considered that $x_{n+1}-x_{n}\geq 0 \iff f(x_n)\geq x_n$, where $f(x)=2x^3-x+\frac{5}{3\sqrt{6}}$.
From the qualitative study of the function $f(x)=2x^3-x+\frac{5}{3\sqrt{6}}$, I have found that in $[0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}]$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \leq f(x)\leq \frac{5}{3\sqrt{6}}$, being $f$ in such interval monotonic decreasing. So for positive $x\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$ then $f(x)\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.
From this I have deduced that $x_{n+1}-x_n\geq 0\iff f(x_n)\geq x_n\iff 0\leq x_n\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$. But now I don't know how to proceed to prove that $0\leq x_n\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$...

$ 0\le x_n\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$ is clearly false, since (you proved yourself that) "for positive $x\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$ then $f(x)\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$".

$f(x)\ge x\iff x\in[a,b]\cup[c,\infty)$, where
$$a=\frac{-1-\sqrt{21}}{2\sqrt6},\quad b=\frac1{\sqrt6},\quad c=\frac{-1+\sqrt{21}}{2\sqrt6}.$$
$x_1=f(0)\in[a,b]$ and $f([a,b])\subset[a,b]$ hence
$$\forall n\ge1\quad x_n\in[a,b]$$ and the sequence $(x_n)$ is decreasing, and converges to $a$.
Edit (on request by comment). To find $a$ and $c$, I substituted $x=\frac y{\sqrt6}$ in the cubic equation $f(x)-x=0$, resulting in $0=y^3-6y+5=(y-1)(y^2+y-5)$, and solved the remaining quadratic equation.

thanks for your answer...but how do you have obtained a and c??
